# How do i prove a given function is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, gamma-function

Lebesgue Integral - Frank Jones p.201

I'm trying to prove $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w)=\Gamma(z+w)B(z,w)$ ($z,w$ are complex numbers with positive real part).

If you know an easier way to prove this, please tell me.. :) This property for real variables is easy but i think Fubini is invincible for complex variables.

I will describe a function of which i want to know its measurability.

========

Let $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $Re(z),Re(w)>0$.

Define $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $F(x)=x^{z-1}e^{-x}$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $0$ otherwise.

Define $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0<x<y\}$

Define $G:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $G(x,y)=(y-x)^{w-1}e^{-(y-x)}$ on $D$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now, define $L(x,y)=F(x)G(x,y), \forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

How do i prove that $L$ is Lebesgue measurable? Moreover, Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: It's continuous therefore measurable.

Comment: If you're referring to the principal branch, then $\lvert F(x)\rvert=e^{-x}\exp((\Re z-1)\log x)$, $G(x,y)$ is similar, and the integrable for the complex case is reduced to the integrable for the real case ($z\gets\Re z,w\gets\Re w$). You said that the real case is easy.